# RMI or Web Services sample application

Tags: java, .net, web-services

Does anyone know of a sample distributed application (.NET or J2EE) using RMI or Web Services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here's a simple solution:**

[BEA Weblogic](http://www.bea.com/framework.jsp?CNT=index.htm&FP=/content/products/weblogic/server) has a sample web application called **MedRec** that I've been using for a while. This sample comes with a .NET client built in called **CSharpClient** that connects to MedRec via Web Services. I was thrilled that I didn't need to install anything else.

In Weblogic 10 the client can be found in the folder "bea\wlserver_10.0\samples\server\medrec\src\clients\CSharpClient".

Answer (score 1):

As often, Sun has an excellent tutorial on RMI:
http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/rmi/index.html

Comment: that's a good example. for tutorial purposes, though, you can skip running the registry from the os (here under "starting the server") and just use createRegistry() instead of getRegistry() on the server's side.

Answer (score 1):

A RMI example: [link](http://yama-linux.cc.kagoshima-u.ac.jp/~yamanoue/researches/java/rmi-ex2/)

A Web Service example: [link](http://www.artima.com/lejava/articles/threeminutes.html)

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Another powerful bare bone working RMI example that loads dynamic objects from the client to server and execute it there then return the results. This can easily expanded for full featured distributed computing environment.

http://www.ningzhang.info/example.java.rmi.ComputeEngine